# Python3, Gtk3 - GtkGrid expanding

Tags: python, gtk

A `GtkWindow` containing a `GtkGrid` containing some `GtkLabel`s won't expand when the window is grown. I want the grid to expand horizontally.

```
grid.set_hexpand(True) #No result
grid.expand = True     #No result
```

The `GtkLabel` in the rightmost column is set to align right so I can accurately see if it's being expanded or not:

```
label.set_halign(Gtk.Align.END)
```

Am I misunderstanding how a grid works? (A `GtkTable` had a set amount of columns, perhaps the `GtkGrid` doesn't and relies on it's sub elements being set to expand?)

Comment: Did you try to set your labels to expand? I think that is the way it is supposed to work - a container widget asks for its  childrens size requirements and allocates its own, as well as the child widgets size accordingly.

Comment: Yes that seems to have been the issue. Still rather strange that there's no way to set the grid to expand and let the contents fill.

Comment: The "expand" property of the gird itself is for the grid with grids-parent rlationship, that concepts is kept for _all_ widgets (not limited to containers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a `GtkGrid` to expand horizontally, you need to set the [`hexpand`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--hexpand) and [`hexpand-set`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--hexpand-set) properties of one the widgets **contained** in the grid.

Just use

```
label.set_hexpand(True)
```

The [gtk_widget_set_hexpand](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-hexpand) method automatically sets both properties.

Comment: Basically what was in the comments. Was just hoping there was a way to reverse propogate expansion or something (grid set to expand, children set to fill)

Comment: @JV You can connect the [`"add"`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer-add) signal of the `GtkGrid`(which is a `GtkContainer`) to the `hexpand` property of all children added to it, I think it will have the effect you expect.